# How to call Ajax within an Each loop without Async:false Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, loops, asynchronous

I have the following HTML structure and I would like to fill each block with an Ajax call but when I use async:false it doesn't work in Jquery 3x

```
<ul class="tray" id="hiphop"></ul>
<ul class="tray" id="rnb"></ul>
<ul class="tray" id="afro"></ul>
<ul class="tray" id="blues"></ul>
<ul class="tray" id="dancehall"></ul>
<ul class="tray" id="rumba"></ul>
<ul class="tray" id="samba"></ul>
<ul class="tray" id="trap"></ul>
<ul class="tray" id="rap"></ul>
```

What I want to perform is this:

- browse the HTML structure and retrieve all the IDs
- send a request to my server file for each ID and
- display the result obtained according to the ID of each block

Here is my initial JS code:

```
$('.tray').each(function(){
    $id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'feed',
        data: 'c='+$id,
        cache: false,
        // async: false, 
        success:function(datas){
            $('#'+$id+'').html(datas);=
        },
        error:function (){
            console.log('error ...');
        }
    });
});
```

but after reading about something called Promise, I tried this but to be honnest, I don't even understand what I'm doing

```
var $array = $.map($('ul.tray'), function(value, index) {
    return [value];
});

var promises = [];
$array.forEach(function(item) {
    // you can access item.id and item.title here
    $id = $(this).attr('id');
    promises.push(
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'feed',
            data: 'c='+$id,
            cache: false,
        })
    );
});
Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
    // all ajax calls done here, results is an array of responses
    //console.log($results);
});
```

Can you please help me to fill those empty blocks with Ajax without using async?
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use the `let` keyword to define a block-scoped reference to the element in the loop so that it's retained within the callback of the AJAX request. Try this:

```
$('.tray').each(function() {
  let $tray = $(this);

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'feed',
    data: 'c=' + this.id,
    cache: false,
    success: function(datas) {
      $tray.html(datas);
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log('error...');
    }
  });
});
```

However it's worth noting that making AJAX requests in a loop is not good practice as it will be flooding your server with requests very quickly, and will not scale with concurrent site visits. A far better approach is to make a *single* AJAX request which gets data for all `.tray` elements and updates them in one go.

Comment: Thank you @Rory for your answer it works very well. Also, I can go with your approach if you tell me how to do